# Prove that an invertible covariance matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance, positive-definite

How to show that invertible covariance matrix $C$ is positive definite?

Comment: Start with the definition. Show your work.

Comment: A covariance matrix is positive semidefinite, and if it's invertible it has no $0$ eigenvalues.

Comment: In one exercise i have to show that covariance matrix is positive semidefinite, and now i have to show that if this matrix is also invertible, then its positive definite. So what now if we know that invertible matrix doesnt have a 0 eigenvalues?